# JDK 1.8 compatibility with JSF 1.2 and Hibernate 3.5.1

Tags: java-8, jsf-1.2, hibernate3

I would like upgrade a project in which I use the JDK 1.6.0.45 with JDK 1.8.

The key components of the projects are:

- jsf 1.2
- hibernate 3.5.1

and these are working well with the JDK 1.6.0.45.

Do you know if there is some problem upgrading the JDK to 1.8 version?

Comment: Hi @enneppi , I also have jdk 6 and jsf 1. We are also upgrading to java 8 and currently i am facing issue with `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();` and this is throwing _java.lang.VerifyError: Inconsistent stackmap frames at branch target 922_ error. Can you please tell me if you faced the same exception or not? And any other issues as well if any. Thanks.